# How to make Riemann rearrangement?

Tags: sequences-and-series

The Riemann arrangement series of real numbers says that if $\pi: \mathbb N\rightarrow \mathbb N$ be any bijection, then from the conditionally convergent  series of real numbers $\sum a_n$, we can create any series $\sum a_{\pi(n)}$ through rearrangement so that it will converge to any real number or it will diverge to either $\infty$ or $-\infty$.

But I don't know how this can be done. I mean to say, if there is an alternating series $\sum (-1)^n a_n$ is given, how can I make it converge to preassigned $x_0\in \mathbb R$ or to diverge to $\infty$ or $-\infty$ ?

Kindly show me the procedure. I want to learn. Or at least provided me some like from where I can get detailed explanations/ source materials etc.

P.S. What if we are given a series of arbitrary terms instead of alternating series?

Comment: Here is one reference: http://www.math.washington.edu/~morrow/335_14/history%20of%20rearrangements.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since partitions your sequence into two subsequences: one with positive elenent and one with negative (or zero) ones. Since your series converges, both subsequences converge to $0$ but since your series doesn't converge absolutely, their sums diverge. So the idea is tha you take as first element any element of your sequence and then, if your current sum is over the $x$ you want the limit to be, you take an element from the negative subsequence and if it's under, you take one from the positive subsequence. Since both subsums diverge you know that you won't stay blocked in one case so you'll end up using all elements.